# jquery side category menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have created a dynamic side category menu.....in jquery, But its sometimes doesn't work properly...i dont know the reason behind,,,, i'd given the code static (picked from the firebug). plz see it soon & if the **code could be more better and the menu could more smooth in working** than it is(given), then plz provide me that code or link...
**thnku**

**javascript(with static id etc.)**

**problem:**

**if i fastly more than one times hover on that li, it gets sliding up & sliding down repeating itself as much times as hover on it.......... ??????????**

```
 $(document).ready(function () { $(' #cate_id2 > ul').show(); });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(' #cate_id2 > ul > #subcate_id4 > div').hide();

            $(' #cate_id2 > ul > #subcate_id4 ').hover(function () {
                $(' #cate_id2 > ul > #subcate_id4 > div').slideDown("fast");
            },

           function () {
               $(' #cate_id2 > ul > #subcate_id4 > div').slideUp("fast");
           });
        });
```

**html(static code)**

```
         <li id="cate_id2">
               <a href="CateProducts.aspx">Laptops &amp; Notebooks</a>  
            <ul style="display: block;">
               <li id="subcate_id3">
                     <a href="SubCateProducts.aspx"> MACS</a>
               </li>
               <li id="subcate_id4">
                     <a href="SubCateProducts.aspx"> Windows</a>
                <div style="border: 1px solid black; display: none;">
                   <ul style="border: 1px solid black; display: block;">
                      <li><a href="SubSubCateProducts.aspx">notebook</a></li>
                      <li><a href="SubSubCateProducts.aspx">probook</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
               </li>
             </ul>
          </li>
```

if u will provide me the code , better then given above
i will convert that(your) code into dynamic myself .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make cleaner:

```
$(function () {
   $('#cate_id2 > ul').show();
   $('#cate_id2 > ul > li')
        .on('mouseover', function () {
            $(this).find('div').stop(true, true).slideDown();
        })
        .on('mouseout', function () {
            $(this).find('div').stop(true, true).slideUp();
        });
});
```

Comment: so, it works now.. added some stop calls (see updated code) to handle your animation problem. please don't forget to vote up and accept if this works.